# Force distinct color for discrete values in plotly

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

If I pass in some discrete data into plotly, it will automatically populate all the values with some ~15 colors) (ex. {"1":blue, "2",:red, ..., "16": blue, "17":red, ...}). How can I ensure all discrete values have distinct colors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have 26 or fewer colors, then you can use `px.colors.qualitative.Alphabet`. If you need more colors than that, you can construct a longer palette by appending together multiple color palettes:

```
my_colors = px.colors.qualitative.Light24 + px.colors.qualitative.Dark24
```

In this case, `my_colors` would have length 48. I believe all of the colors are distinct, though some are close to each other.

For all possible rgb colors you could use the following:

```
all_colors = [f"rgb({r},{g},{b})" for r in range(256) for g in range(256) for b in range(256)]
```

And if you want n distinct colors roughly evenly distributed over all_colors, you can let `k = floor(256^3 / n)`, and iterate through every kth element of `all_colors`

Comment: Is there any method for an unlimited amount of colors?

Comment: unlimited? there's only a finite number of colors that can be generated that are distinguishable from one another. if you use `rgb(x, y, z)` you can technically get 256^3 different colors, but many of them will look nearly identical

Comment: Sure, lets say an upperbound of 2^24 colors (the RGB space). We want them to be as distinguishable as possible, but if you have 256^3 colors, this means that the colors will have to look nearly identical

Comment: i've updated my answer accordingly @olivarb. if you want the colors to be more distinguishable, you can iterate over every kth element where k is a sufficiently large integer

Comment: The update works assuming we have 256^3 elements. If we have some number of elements (0 < n ≤ 256^3), how would we generate a color scale that is evenly distributed. I imagine `rgb(i*k,i*k,i*k)` is not an optimal way to do this nor is `rgb(k %256, k/256 %256, k/256^2 %256)` for 256^2 < k ≤ 256^3.

Comment: @olivarb you could let `k = floor(256^3/n)` for n colors to get something roughly evently distributed